# Selenium WebDriver - IE 8 - Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, server

I am using Selenium WebDriver to run my tests on IE 8/Windows 2008 Server. I got the error "Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones". The fix was to switch on/off the mode in all four zones. Even though I did it I still get the same error. I **can't** get the tests to run without using InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS flag. I wanted to check if I am missing anything since its Windows 2008 server.

Same issue is mentioned here:

http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html

I tried disabling and enabling protected mode for all zones. I still get the same error:

> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unexpected error launching Internet
>   Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones.
>   Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or
>   disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 1.03 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision:
>   '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23
>   13:11:40' System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'

What else am I missing here?

Comment: Mention what issue you are facing instead of adding a link..

Comment: @Karna, I am using Selenium WebDriver to run my tests on IE 8/Windows 2008 Server. I got the error "Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones". The fix was to switch on/off the mode in all four zones. Even though I did it I still get the same error. I **can't** get the tests to run without using InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS flag. I wanted to check if I am missing anything since its Windows 2008 server.

Answer (score 0):

•On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode". 
•Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog. 
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Of course disabling Enhanced Protected Mode is a red flag to your security people and they will not allow it. Why MS would throw such a monkey wrench Selenium's way and so inconvenience their many customers is an interesting question.

As for INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS  see:
http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html 
for why you shouldn't.